# hi, it is possible to detect on react that the page is rendering by a ctrl+shift+t command?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, web-deployment

it is possible to detect on react that the page is rendering by a ctrl+shift+t  command ?  for example, i need to detect this situation:

1. The user closes the browser tab
2. Then the user press ctrl+shift+t to re-open the tab
3. I then identify that the tab was opened from a ctrl+shift+t  command

Is this possible ? How ?

Update:
I have this piece of code on my page:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
        //some stuff
    }
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleResize);

    return function cleanupListener() {
      console.log('backing')
     
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleResize);
    };
  }, []);
```

When i click to go to this page, i make a history.push(/chat).
Then if i click on back button the console.log 'backing' is shown.
But if i close the tab and re-open, if i click on back button, the console.log doesn't show  :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are probably a thousand other ways to "reopen the tab" or *re-visit the page* or whatever. What are you really trying to prevent, ultimately?

Comment: I updated my question to be more clear about what i'm trying to do. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because you cannot get the user key press events when it's out of focus from the dom.

But you can prevent or warn user from closing the tab,

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
        });
```

Comment: Hi, sorry my question wans't clear  i updated it.  I'm confuse about why when we re open the tab the eventListener  'popstate' is not added to the tab  :/